# Mock module using Vue CLI and mochapack

Tags: unit-testing, webpack, mocha.js, vue-cli

I use a tiny part of the Electron API in my Electron app, and for unit tests it would be great to be able to mock the `electron` module, so that when I do `import "electron"` deep in my tests it loads my mocked version instead of failing to load the real one.

I am aware of Spectron, and I did try to set it up, but it is just a complete mess of outdated dependencies and meaningless error messages and I gave up fighting it. It also doesn't seem to support headless mode so is massive overkill for my tests.

I am also are that Jest has a `jest.mock()` function that seems to be designed for this purpose, but I am not using Jest, and in any case telling Webpack to just entirely replace the module seems like a cleaner solution.

I *think* I should be able to use [Webpack aliases](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) to do this, something like:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'electron': path.resolve(__dirname, 'tests/fake_electron.js'),
  },
},
```

But I have no idea how to tell Vue CLI to use that webpack configuration when running `test:unit`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This works!

```
// package.json
...
  "scripts": {
    "test:unit": "ENABLE_MODULE_MOCKS=1 vue-cli-service test:unit",
```

```
// vue.config.js

const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.ENABLE_MODULE_MOCKS) {
      console.log("Enabling module mocks");
      config.resolve.alias.set(
        "electron",
        path.resolve(__dirname, "tests/mocks/electron.js"),
      );
    }
  },
};
```

```
// tests/mocks/electron.js

export const remote = {
  app: {
    isPackaged: false,
    getAppPath: () => "foo",
  },
  // Add more mocks as required.
};
```

I haven't bothered trying to integrate it with Typescript, because this build system is insane enough already.